# Prove A is invertible if a norm condition is satisfied

Tags: real-analysis

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional Banach space and $A \in L(V,V).$ I need to prove the statement: if there exists $\mu>0$ with $\| \mu I_n-A\|<\mu, $ then $A$ is invertible.

Dividing by $\mu$ we get, $\|I_n-\frac{1}{\mu}A\|<1.$ If we set $B:=I_n-\frac{1}{\mu}A,$ we may use the lemma related to the Neumann series, indicating that under these assumptions, $I_n-B$ is invertible and the following holds, $(I_n - B)^{-1}= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} B^k.$ We notice that $I_n-B = \frac{1}{\mu} A.$ Thus, $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\mu}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (I_n-\frac{1}{\mu} A)^k.$ Given that $\|B \|<1, $ we know that the geometric series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \|B \|^k$ converges. We prove that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} B^k$ is convergent by proving that the partial sum is a Cauchy sequence and given that $V$ is a Banach space, it thus converges. For a given $\epsilon >0 \,\,\exists\, l, m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that following holds: $$ \sum _{k=0}^l A^k - \sum _{k=0}^{m-1} A^k = \sum _{k=m}^{l} A^k \leq \sum _{k=m}^{l} \|A^k\|\leq \sum _{k=m}^{l} \|A\|^k<\epsilon. $$

I do not know how to go from here. Thanks for any comment or a solution proposal.

Comment: If $I_n - B$ is invertible, then $\frac{1}{\mu}A$ is invertible. Then $A$ is invertible.